# MVC 5 Unintentional, Automatic Redirection to non existent URL

Tags: asp.net, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5

When I start my new ASP.NET MVC 5 App, I get redirected to `http://localhost:54044/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F`, where it shows me a 404-Error, even though there is neither a Account-Controller, a Login View, nor do I call a `RedirectToAction` Method anywhere in my App. This even happens with a new, blank Project that only has a Home/Index View. This happens both in Firefox and Chrome.
What is causing this Redirection to happen?
I uploaded the Source Code to GitHub [here](https://github.com/Creeperagent26/MVC-Problem).

Comment: Are you hosting this application inside another application where form authentication is enabled?  On side note try changing port number in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line #10 in `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs` you have a global authorization filter set up.

```
filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

Remove it.

Comment: Thnak you! That fixed the Problem.